# Nutch2 not resuming crawl

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using the below command in Nutch 2.3.1 with MongoDB storage. When it is crawling, the process is by pressing CTRL+C. After that, if I try to run the same crawl script, it is not simply breaking without any error. It exits in the second iteration.

Command used : runtime/local/bin/crawl urls/  'crawlDb' 10

**Output:**

> ParserJob: finished at 2018-03-02 19:48:31, time elapsed: 00:00:02
> CrawlDB update for crawlDb
> /Users/rajeevprasanna/Desktop/nutch-cassandra/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch
> updatedb -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m
> -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D
> mapred.compress.map.output=true 1520000291-27137 -crawlId crawlDb
> DbUpdaterJob: starting at 2018-03-02 19:48:31
> DbUpdaterJob: batchId: 1520000291-27137
> DbUpdaterJob: finished at 2018-03-02 19:48:34, time elapsed: 00:00:02
> Skipping indexing tasks: no SOLR url provided.
> Fri Mar 2 19:48:34 IST 2018 : Iteration 2 of 10
> Generating batchId
> Generating a new fetchlist
> /Users/rajeevprasanna/Desktop/nutch-cassandra/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch
> generate -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m
> -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D
> mapred.compress.map.output=true -topN 50000 -noNorm -noFilter -adddays
> 0 -crawlId crawlDb -batchId 1520000314-30627
> GeneratorJob: starting at 2018-03-02 19:48:34
> GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
> GeneratorJob: starting
> GeneratorJob: filtering: false
> GeneratorJob: normalizing: false
> GeneratorJob: topN: 50000
> GeneratorJob: finished at 2018-03-02 19:48:37, time elapsed: 00:00:02
> GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1520000314-30627 containing 0 URLs
> Generate returned 1 (no new segments created)
> Escaping loop: no more URLs to fetch now
> Rajeevs-MacBook-Pro:apache-nutch-2.3.1 rajeevprasanna$

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as shown: "no more URLs to fetch now". There are no new unfetched links in the web table. To resume from scratch the CrawlDb (web table) in MongoDb needs to be removed.

Comment: Currently i am removing the database. If we remove the database, crawl will start from zero state. How can we resume without resetting the crawl state?

Answer (score 0):

Well There is a -resume parameter for these commands, it should work.